# How to remove the new line added with .toYaml in helm?

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I added the following section to values.yaml of a helm chart:

```
   extraEnv:
      - name: APPSERVER_RETURN_CLIENT_ERRORS
        value: true
```

And used those values in deployment.yaml as:

```
  env:
    - name: DYNA_GATEWAY_HOST
      value: "$(DYNAGATEWAY_SERVICE_HOST)"
  {{- with .Values.extraEnv }}
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 12 }}
  {{- end }}
```

But when it reads, it appends a new line after the env section as :

```
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  env:
    - name: DYNA_GATEWAY_HOST
      value: "$(DYNAGATEWAY_SERVICE_HOST)"
    - name: APPSERVER_RETURN_CLIENT_ERRORS
      value: true

  ports:
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sprig [`trim`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html) function will remove leading and trailing whitespace.  In terms of the pipeline, you want to do this before `nindent` puts a leading newline in front of it.

```
{{- toYaml . | trim | nindent 12 }}
```

Your other option, if you know `toYaml` will always include a trailing newline (it will whenever `.Values.extraEnv` is a non-empty list or dictionary), is to try to suppress the whitespace around it

```
{{- with .Values.extraEnv }}
  {{- toYaml . | nindent 12 }}
{{/*   vvv add this hyphen */}}
{{- end -}}
```

but this can interfere with the indentation on the following line.